# Laravel, count collection where relationship field equal value

Tags: laravel

How can i count relationships on my collection (in Blade)?

Like this:

```
{{ $characters->where($characters->spec->id, '10')->count() }}
```

Comment: What relationship? Update your question and include details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your model "belongsTo" to add the relationship:

```
    public function requests() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Request', 'id', 'desired_date_id');
    }
```

and to your controller you can add:

```
    ->withCount('requests')
```

with that you get a new field called "request_count" with the count of the relationships.

At your blade template you can simply add `->request_count` to show the value.

[Laravel Belongs To Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

[Laravel Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)